# macのコマンドライン環境での日本語入力について

Tags: macos, postgresql, 文字化け

PostgreSQL 9.6.xをEnterpriseDBのイメージからインストールしたのですが、psql上での日本語入力が文字化けしてしまいます。Sierra上でiTerm2使ってますが、Windows上のPuTTYからリモートログインしてやっても状況は同じです。

```
=> select * from 家計簿;
```

といった感じにすると、どうも「計」が抜けてしまうみたい(家簿、になってテーブルがない扱い)ですし「日本語」とか入れると"???"になってます。
テキストを作ってリダイレクトで流し込むとうまくいくので、psqlの問題だと思います。

この件について調べてみると .inputrc ファイルの書き換えとか\encodingで設定とか出てくるのですがどれをやっても状況に差はありません。

結局 `psql -n` でreadlineを殺して入れるという方法でやってます。
この部分に対しての現状と、"-n無しで文字化けしない"最新のアプローチをご存知の方がいたら教えてください。

Comment: 環境変数（envコマンドで確認できる）のLC_CTYPEは何になってますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。ロケール系変数のことですね。sshでリモートログインする限りではja_JP.UTF-8になってました(localeで確認）、念のため `LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8 psql` で走らせても状況は同じです。